# SQL IF Doesn't work

Tags: mysql, sql

Im using Wampserver 2.1 with mysql version 5.1.53.

This query:

```
SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE 1
```

runs, while this query

```
IF 1 
SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE 1
```

Doesn't, I get the error :

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF 1 SELECT * FROM`contents`WHERE 1' at line 1`

I have looked up for 'IF' syntax dozens  of times and can't find the problem.
Why would this happen?

Comment: Define *doesn't run*. Do you get an error?

Comment: I may be wrong but think that it is only valid in routines in MySQL rather than adhoc queries.

Comment: *IF* is not allowed in this context ... from your question it is not really clear, what you would like to achieve. Maybe we can help you, if you provide more details on what you want to do ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IF statements are for Flow Control Constructs within stored programs.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/flow-control-constructs.html

Comment: IF 1 = 1 THEN
SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE 1
End IF doesn't work either

Comment: @TheGiG - You would need to use `DELIMITER $$ CREATE PROCEDURE foo() BEGIN /*Your code*/ END` then `call foo`

Comment: Check http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/if-statement.html for an example. IF statements work inside functions.

Comment: @TheGiG - The "YourCode" bit needs to be `IF 1 THEN SELECT * FROM contents WHERE 1;  END IF;`

Answer (score 1):

There are two `IF`s in MySQL: the [control-flow IF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) and the [IF statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/if-statement.html) for procedures. You'd need to either create a stored routine (where you could then use `IF...THEN...`), or use `SELECT ... IF(...)`.

Comment: IF 1 = 1 THEN
SELECT * FROM `contents` WHERE 1
End IF doesn't work either

Comment: @TheGiG, this won't work if it is not executed within a stored routine. Are you trying this in a stored routine?